# Invalid syntax, Unexpected EOF

Tags: python, eof

What is wrong with my code? 
It says there is an invalid syntax and highlighting the colon?

BTW, I'm doing computing GCSE and this is part of the coursework prep.

I want it to take a letter to repeat and then repeat it an inputted number of times.

```
letter=input("Please enter a letter to be repeated:     ")
number=int(input("Please enter the number of times you want it repeated:     ")

for a in range(0,number):
       print(+letter)
```

Comment: You should add in the tags the programming language you're using.

Comment: thanks @ Marco Aurélio Deleu

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you're debugging, compilers and interpreters will report where an error was first *detected*, not necessarily where the error actually is. You're missing a closing parentheses on this line:

```
number=int(input("Please enter the number of times you want it repeated:     ")
```

Add another `)` to the end of that line. The interpreter is seeing the opening parentheses for the `int` function call, then is happily looking through the rest of the file to find its match. When it reaches the end of the file without the parentheses being balanced, it gives up and throws the exception.

As Josh points out, `+letter`is also invalid syntax. I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with it so I can't recommend a specific fix, but it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your closing parenthesis for the `int()` function call. Also you need to remove the `+` from `print(+letter)`